# UISplitViewControllerDelegate problem

Tags: ios, ipad

I have been creating a new iPad application based on the SplitViewController.  I have modeled the app after the MultipleDetailViews sample app from Apple.  The problem I have is that the splitViewController:willHideViewController:withBarButtonItem:forPopoverController: method is not called at startup when the device starts in Portrait mode.  This method is called during the startup sequence in the MultipleDetailViews sample app.  It is during this call that the button to be presented in the toolbar in the main view should be added.

My application is working fine otherwise, i.e. I get the UISplitViewControllerDelegate calls in every other case.  I can't figure out though why I am not getting the willHideViewController message during startup.

Any thoughts?  Is there some other way I can get at the button to be displayed in the toolbar when starting in portrait mode if not through this willHideViewController message?

Thanks in advance,

-Eric

Comment: Eric - has you managed to resolve this? I encountered the exact same problem (iOS 5.0b5) after replacing a stock Master-Detail template with a navigation controller that encloses a detail view controller.